# Why am I getting an weird error on my asp.net webpage?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, wcf

I am currently developing a asp.net webpage and a WCF publish subscribe service. The WCF service has been done up the subscriber is a winform app which is also done up. I am now trying to get the asp.net webpage to connect to my publish service for my WCF. However there is an weird error that I am getting. I have added the app.config and the generatedProxy.cs.vb to my asp.net project.

This is the code for my class

```
Public Class json
Implements IPostingContractCallback

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

Response.ContentType = "application/json"

If Request.QueryString("action") = "postAlert" Then

        Dim site As InstanceContext = New InstanceContext(New json())
        Dim client As PostingContractClient = New PostingContractClient(site)

        client.PublishPost("testing")

        client.Close()

    End If
End Sub

Public Sub PostReceived(ByVal postSampleData As String)

    Console.WriteLine("PostChange(item {0})", postSampleData)
End Sub
```

the sub PostReceived is the callback method for my WCF service. It practically is meant to be do nothing as this is the Publisher, but I still have to implement it due to the WCF standards. The error that I am getting is

```
Class 'json' must implement 'Sub PostReceived(postSampleData As String)' for interface 'IPostingContractCallback'
```

How come i am getting the error when i have already implemented the sub as stated above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method signature must be: (Take a look at [VB.NET Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/28e2e18x%28v=VS.100%29.aspx))

```
Public Sub PostReceived(ByVal postSampleData As String) Implements IPostingContractCallback.PostReceived
    Console.WriteLine("PostChange(item {0})", postSampleData)
End Sub
```

Comment: @AVD - Implicit implementation wouldn't work here?  Or am I missing something else?